# Python: numba, how can constructor take a function as an argument?

Tags: python, numba

I want to learn to use numba. Unfortunatly I am finding it a bit difficult to learn numba from the documentation. So I have to try to ask you guys. I want to pass a function `f` as an argument to a constructor. However I try, I get all sorts of errors. What should I do?

Here's my code:

```
def f(x):
    # return some mathematical expression

f_numba = jit(double(double))(f)

@autojit
class name:
    def __init__(self, f)
        self.f = f

    @double(double)
    def __call__(self, x)
        return self.f(x)

funct = name(f_numba)
a = funct(5)
```

Here are some of the error I am getting ( I am sorry that the indentation and line breaks are not preserved. I tried a few different things, but in all cases the formating is lost). I am posting this because I was asked to in the comments. But the kind of errors I am getting varies with the exact implementation:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/marius/dev/python/inf1100/test_ODE.py", line 7, in 
>        from DE import *   File "/home/marius/dev/python/inf1100/DE.py", line 3, in 
>       @autojit   File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/decorators.py",
>   line 183, in autojit
>       nopython=nopython, locals=locals, **kwargs)(func)   File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/decorators.py",
>   line 165, in _autojit_decorator
>       numba_func = wrapper(f, compilerimpl, cache)   File "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/exttypes/autojitclass.py",
>   line 360, in autojit_class_wrapper
>       py_class = autojitmeta.create_unspecialized_cls(py_class, class_specializer)   File
>   "/home/marius/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/exttypes/autojitmeta.py",
>   line 22, in create_unspecialized_cls
>       class AutojitMeta(type(py_class)): TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       type 'classobj' is not an acceptable base type

Comment: "I get all sorts of errors" isn't very specific.  Generally, if you get an error, it's best to post it here so that we know what we're dealing with.  See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for a great tutorial on how to ask great questions.

Comment: Could you post the actual errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using a [new-style class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/20862) instead.

```
@autojit
class name(object):
```